# Welch statistic

Tags: mathematical-statistics, hypothesis-testing

How to get the distribution of Welch Statstic:
$ \sum_t w_t(y_t - \hat{y})^2 $
in journal article [*On the Comparison of Several Mean Values: An Alternative Approach*](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=Welch%2C+B.+L.+%281951%29.+On+the+comparison+of+several+mean+values%3A+An+alternative+approach.+Biometrika%2C+38%2C+330-336.&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.soph.uab.edu%2FStatgenetics%2FPeople%2FMBeasley%2FCourses%2FWelch1951.pdf&ei=pDPdULH6NIn5rQe--oGwAg&usg=AFQjCNE9v2uBUWrJl5dtliD-qJ_mpuT81A) (Welch, 1951)?

Comment: can you specify how $y_t$ are distributed? If $y_t$ are iid normal then your distribution should be some kind of Chi-squared since it is kind of a sum of squared normal variables.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Are you wanting to try to find the *true* distribution in finite samples of this quantity? Or, are you looking to understand the moment-matching approach in Section 4?

Comment: I want to know both. I don't really understand the notations in that journal article, so if there are other ways to find the distribution, I would like to know it.